# In C# can you return a default int value from main?

Tags: c#

I want to return a default int value from main.

Consider the following:

```
using System;
class Class1
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        int intReturnCode = 1;
        int intRandNumber;

        Random myRandom = new Random();
        intRandNumber = myRandom.Next(0,2);
        if(intRandNumber ==1)
        {
            throw new Exception("ErrorError");      
        }
        return intReturnCode;
    }
}
```

When the exception is reached I don't get to set the returncode.

Is it possible to have a default return code inside of main?

**Clarification:** I have a program that is throwing Unhandled Exceptions. I have the application inside a try catch, however some errors (probably out of memory, stackoverflow etc) are still bubling up and causing my application to fail in production.

To fix this I've added code to capture unhandled exceptions.

This was added to main:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);
```

And now I have this method that is reached when an unhandled exception occurs.

```
public static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)   
{ 
    //here's how you get the exception  

    Exception exception = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;                 

    //bail out in a tidy way and perform your logging
}
```

The prblem is that I'm no longer in Main and I want to exit with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: `catch` the exception, and return a code in the `finally` block.

Comment: Your last line of code will never be executed if intRandNumber ==1. The solution is to catch the exception and return your code from there.

Comment: Actually, he's throwing the exception himself - why would it catch it? The question is why he's throwing it at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An unhandled exception is **implementation defined behaviour**.  Anything can happen; the CLR can decide to set the return code of the process as it sees fit, it can start a debugger, it can do whatever it wants. You cannot rely on any behaviour of any program that contains an unhandled exception.

If you want to have predictable behaviour, like determining what the return code is when the process ends, then there must be a total of *zero* unhandled exceptions.

If you have a third party component that is throwing unhandled out of memory exceptions then your best bet is: *fix the bug in that component*. If you can't do that then *isolate the component into its own process or its own appdomain*.

Comment: Wow Eric answered my question. I feel like I've been touched by the finger of a (c#) god. I'm getting this error in production: “Application popup: StoredProcLauncher.exe - Application Error : The instruction at "0x7c82c912" referenced memory at "0x00000000". The memory could not be "read”. The catch is missing this error and the error is bubbling up to Tidal. I'm trying to resolve this.

Comment: @codingguy3000: You have some unmanaged code that is dereferencing a null pointer. Do you know what DLL the code at 0x7c82c912 came from? That might not be the DLL with the bug -- the null pointer could have been supplied to it by some other buggy code -- but it would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

The question is really why you are throwing an exception in `main` instead of providing a return code that indicates an error? Instead of what you're doing, my code would look as follows:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    int intRandNumber;

    try
    {
        Random myRandom = new Random();
        intRandNumber = myRandom.Next(0,2);
        if(intRandNumber ==1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got invalid random number!");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Strange ... an error occurred! " + exp.ToString());
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

As a rule of thumb you should never throw exceptions to control program flow. If you can, handle conditions like *oops, I got the wrong number* without throwing an exception.

Comment: Exactly, this is the more logical way of coding.

Comment: Thorsten can you review my additional details. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Throwing an exception in the main thread ends execution without reaching the `return`: that's when you get the "Console application has stopped working, would you like to debug?" dialog from the operating system. The `Main` cannot return anything under these conditions, because there is nothing to return.

If you would like to return something when you get an exception, code your program like this:

```
// Put your implementation into a private method
private static int DoWork(string[] args) {
    ... // Do actual work, and throw exceptions if you need to
    return intReturnCode;
}
// The Main method calls the implementation, and returns the value
// returned from the implementation if everything goes well.
// If an exception is thrown, however, Main could return another value
// of its choice.
public static int Main(string[] args) {
    try {
        return DoWork(args);
    } catch {
        return myDefaultReturnCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

catch your exception and set return statement in finally block

```
using System;
class Class1
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int intReturnCode = 1;
            int intRandNumber;

            Random myRandom = new Random();
            intRandNumber = myRandom.Next(0,2);
            if(intRandNumber ==1)
            {
                throw new Exception("ErrorError");      
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          // ...
        }
        finally
        {
            return intReturnCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could just not throw the exception at all - exceptions should not be used to control program flow.

Comment: +0: I would not use `finally` for that - `try`/`catch` already consists of 2 parts, `finally` adds third part (which is also optional) - so much easier to miss/loose. Also `finally` is significantly less common in regular code - will require more effort to read the code.